# Why isn't this scroll-animate working?

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

Here's a fiddle--- http://jsfiddle.net/mFrbA/2/

Which is just a test for the code below. I'm trying to get it to scroll down all the way, slowly and steadily. The reason I'm not just executing it the straightforward way, by scrolling straight to the bottom of the document, is because I want to do it in increments while giving the user a chance to cancel it (hence the variable `scrolling`, which can be toggled by an outside function.

The reason for the `wait` variable is to (theoretically) prevent the while loop from looping faster than the animation-- I wasn't sure if it would wait for the animation to finish before starting over. But the complete function is never getting called, and the animation is never happening in the first place.

However, none of this is executing. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$(function() {
    scrolling = true;
    while (scrolling) {
        var wait = true; 
        $('html, body').animate(
            { scrollTop: '+=50' }, 
            { duration: 800,
             easing: 'linear',
             complete: function(){
                 alert("hi again");
                 wait = false;}
            }
        );
        while(wait) {
            console.log("waiting");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript in browsers is single-threaded (in practice) with an event loop. Your `while(wait)` ties up JavaScript execution, so the animation (which is asynchronous) never has a chance to happen.

This is why we have callbacks, and there’s pretty much no working around that, except with a horrible `setInterval` thing.

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: @Aerovistae: Just use `animate` once. It takes care of changing the property gradually — that’s what an animation is. You can multiply the duration appropriately.

Comment: But how can I provide the opportunity to stop the animation at any stage along the way?

Comment: @Aerovistae: Keep the return value from `.animate()` and call `.stop()` on it.

Comment: An example in the answer would be heaven-sent. :)

Comment: @Aerovistae: Do you want to multiply the duration, or no?

Comment: @Aerovistae: Also, could you add the rest of the code from your jsFiddle? I can’t see it, because it hangs :D

Comment: This is all the fiddle code. I just filled the HTML part with a ton of `<p>hi</p>` to give me something to scroll.